# How can I package a subproject for compile time dependency in a another subproject using SBT?

Tags: sbt

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

I have two projects A and B. Project A depends on Project B for compile time validation. More specifically Project B provides compile time annotation-processing for project A. Compile time annotation processing requires a jar file to be registered for compiler to pick it up.

What I need:  Every time I build Project A, Project B should be compiled, packaged and published to the local repository. How do i set this up? Note: I don't need project B for running Project A or for packaging it.

Note: I am using Play-Java for Project A and Project B is just a regular sbt java project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `build.sbt` file in your root project? This kind of setup requires that Project A be able to reference Project B.

If all you require is for Project B to be published, you can simply do something like this in your root `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val projectB = project.in(file("project-b"))
lazy val projectA = project.in(file("project-a")).settings(
  // Note that you need to scope `publishLocal` to projectB.
  compile <<= compile.dependsOn(publishLocal.in(projectB))
)
```